# Updatepanels stop working - possible session timeout

Tags: asp.net, session, updatepanel

I have a page with a couple of update panels on them. When a user stays inactive on the page for 30+ minutes the update panels stop working. The update panel loads some extra fields when a choice is made from a dropdown. However, if no action has been taken on the page for some time the update panel doesn't work. I can see it trigger the Asyn postback but the fields do not appear.

I thought that it was possibly a session timeout issue so I have modified the web config to have a session timeout of 240. And I also set the idle timeout on the app pool in IIS to 240. I followed the directions here: http://asp-net.vexedlogic.com/2012/05/23/aspasp-net-session-timeout-how-do-i-change-it/

However I still have the problem. Is there any way to isolate and solve the problem? It seems like a session timeout but the config/IIS changes didn't help.

```
<sessionState timeout="240">
</sessionState>
```

If the user navigates to another page and comes back then things function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In case, if update panel takes more time to process set `AsyncPostBackTimeout` property of your ScriptManager. `Default is 90 secs`

```
 <asp:ScriptManager AsyncPostBackTimeout="3000" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. The problem isn't with the update panel taking too long to process. It is with a timeout from inactivity on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Microsoft's KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2915218), you should create `machineKey` using Windows PowerShell then copy-paste it into web.config `<system.web>` section.